# Massive dilaton

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes, black-hole-thermodynamics

Dilaton field is one of the matter fields which comes from the string theory. However, people consider it as a scalar field in black hole physics, so the dilaton particle in this regard is spinless. In the low energy limit, the mass of dilaton is zero and also it has no charge. So, all three quantum numbers of dilaton are zero. Why we use this field when we know that it can not exist?

Also, in some theories, people consider mass for dilaton. But, it is not very usual. Please, I need more information about massive dilaton since there is a little information in the literature.

Comment: What's your source for saying a particle can't satisfy $m=0,\,Q=0,\,S=0$?

Comment: Re. J. G:
It is a scalar field so S=0.  Also in many papers, the authors emphasize that they took the mass of dilaton  m=0 (for example please study : arXiv:hep-th/9502054). Regarding dilaton charge, in some papers, people take it as zero (they ignore dilaton charge in their theory, please study: arXiv:0912.4199). In the last case, all quantum numbers are zero, this manuscript is published in physical review D.

Comment: I'm referring to your saying, "Why we use this field when we know that it can not exist?" I'm asking why it cannot.

Comment: Re. J. G: 
As I know, with respect to particle physics, every particle should characterize with these three numbers, and at least one of them should be non-zero.

Comment: I never heard of that theorem.

Comment: Re. J. G: 
So, how do you distinguish particle if you do not use the quantum numbers? How can we detect a real particle which all of its quantum numbers are zero?

Comment: I think you're confusing properties specific to a particle species with properties specific to members of that species. For example, the angular momentum of a particle can differ from its spin, by a state-dependent amount that's a quantum number specific to one particle in the species. Besides which, $S=0$ particles are bosons, so two of them can occupy the same state. How would we detect an $m=Q=S=0$ particle? It depends on how it interacts, but in the case of a dilaton we'd note gravity works differently because of it.

Comment: Re J. G: How can two real particles with zero values for all quantum numbers interact with each other?

Comment: Even if they couldn't do so, they would interact with something, e.g. by gravitational lensing.

Answer (score 1):

In string theory, the quantities of phenomenological interest depend on more fundamental quantities called moduli. The moduli correspond to the sizes of the extra dimensions, separations between branes, and so on. To make a prediction, one needs to calculate or at least estimate the moduli vevs (which will lie at the minimum of some potential, describing the ground state of the dynamical geometry), and this is very difficult (unless supersymmetry is unbroken, but that is not the physically realistic case). So-called "moduli stabilization" is a major area of research.

The dilaton mass and dilaton vev in string theory are examples of this problem. For unbroken supersymmetry, the dilaton mass is zero. In some models, supersymmetry is broken by gaugino condensation in a hidden sector, and there are papers on what the dilaton potential is for this case. You can find further papers by looking for "dilaton stabilization". I am no expert, but I would regard all such results as tentative (relying on some assumptions about the potential) and model-specific (there does not seem to be a "general theory of dilaton stabilization").

A comment on Physics SE once recommended chapter 9 of Gasperini's "Elements of string cosmology" for this topic.